# View complete data frame on r studio

Tags: r, function, filter

How can I get the complete data frame when I use 'filter' function and rstudio just shows me 10 rows but I can read (for example) there's 377 more rows.

Here's the code as an example:

```
> nameofdataframe%>%
+filter( year == 2021)
```

Thank you in advance!
Kind regards,
Helena.

Comment: you can send it to the viewer: `nameofdataframe %>% filter( year == 2021) %>% View()` Otherwise, what's `class(nameofdataframe)` return? Is it a tibble or a data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to base R:

`as.data.frame(nameofdataframe)`

The problem is that the tidyverse uses `tibbles` instead of `data.frame`, and the `print` method for `tibble` is limited to those 10 rows.  Change the class of your table to `data.frame` and print it and you should get the "standard" display.

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio, `View(nameofdataframe)` will open another tab where you can view the full results.  Clicking on `nameofdataframe` in the Environment window will also do the same.